# How to align an image at the middle of a input field?

Tags: html, css, input, alignment

I want to align a small image ao it is at the vertical middle of a textbox **without using tables.** Icurrently have this piece of code:

```
<input type="text" style="border-color: #FF0000; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px; width: 35%; font-size: 30px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
<img src="http://surfcamp.infinibrain.net/images/error.png" style="height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-left: 5px;" /><br/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBMMJ/1/)

As you can see the image sticks to the top of the textbox. I also tried adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to achieve ?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/nBMMJ/8/)**

```
<div class="lol">
    <input type="text" style="border-color: #FF0000; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px; width: 35%; font-size: 30px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
    <img src="http://surfcamp.infinibrain.net/images/error.png" style="height: 32px; width: 32px;" />
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="lol">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <img src="http://surfcamp.infinibrain.net/images/error.png" style="height: 32px; width: 32px;" />
</div>
```

---

```
.lol {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.lol img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:7px;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
.lol input {
    padding-right:40px !Important;
    width:200px !Important;
}
.lol textarea{
    padding-right:40px;
    min-height:30px;
}
```

---

**Update**
For textareas, nothing special is required. I do have an update though. You should display the wrapper div as `inline-block`

Comment: Not what I wanted, but it's even better :D

Comment: FYI, avoid using inline css. It becomes a headache later on. Trust me.

Comment: Well, works and good result, but kind of tricky. I mean: there're other ways to do that without using absolute and stuff.

Comment: @Lokesh How about a resizable textarea with 90 % width? Currently the image is being displayed at 36.5%. So I could change this value to 91.5% but when the user resizes the area the image will be in a wrong position. Also the textarea has multiple lines, so the icon is being displayed in the middle of nowhere in that textarea. Could you please help me out of this one too?

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your input and image either into a div or td if you have, then add vertical-align: middle to img:

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" style="border-color: #FF0000; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px; width:     35%; font-size: 30px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
    <img src="http://surfcamp.infinibrain.net/images/error.png" style="height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" /><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are well.. a number of ways to accomplish what you want to do. 
I'll tell you two ways to do that. Remember that there's not a "must" in these situations. You've have to choose (not necessarily one of those i'm telling you)  the way that best suits your needs (layout needs, etc)

**Relative Positioning**

http://jsfiddle.net/nBMMJ/4/

Giving an element `position:relative` and setting a value to it's `top` property may give you a nice result.

**Vertical Align Bottom**

http://jsfiddle.net/nBMMJ/6/

To align an image you can use `vertical-align:bottom`. In this case, to help centering, I used the `margin-bottom`.